# [Angular 6]Passing code into a component dynamically

Tags: angular

anyone knows if it is possible to pass a piece of HTML code into a component, which is interpreted inside the component instead of at the parent.

For example,

```
<my-component>Hello {{variableInsideTheComponent}}</my-component>
```

which variableInsideTheComponent refers to a variable defined inside the component scope.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the variable as an input variable:

`@Input() variableInsideTheComponent: string`

Then display the variable in a span, setting the `innerHtml` attribute:

`<span [innerHtml]="variableInsideTheComponent"></span>`

However, depending on where you're taking the input from, you may wish to use the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#sanitize) to ensure that the HTML is safe to parse.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Do you mean to do the coding inside the [xxx] block? e.g. <my-component [variableInsideTheComponent]=" 'code...' "></my-component>

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. I've just put this together in a StackBlitz so you can see it working - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o4m3sc